# R cumulative sum of one variable while another variable tracks "cutoff"

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

What I'd like to do is find the sum of the sepal lengths of iris flowers that are over each "critical value" of petal width / petal length.

Consider the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
data("iris")       
 iris <- iris %>% 
      mutate(prop_width_length = Petal.Width/Petal.Length)
    
    prop_width_length <-  as.data.frame(iris$prop_width_length)
    
    portion = as.data.frame(seq(0,1,0.001))
    cumsum = NULL
    
    
    for (i in 1:1001) {
      cumsum[i] = sum(prop_width_length >= portion[i,1])
    }

sigportion <-  cbind(portion, cumsum)
```

That gives me a cumulative sum of how many of my iris flowers have a width/length proportion greater than or equal to each "critical value". Then finally it puts it in a data frame so I can make a nice ggplot. Basically it counts how many flowers have over each "critical value".

What I'd like to in addition to the above code is add up all of the sepal lengths for every iris where their petal width/length ratio is greater than or equal to each "critical value" stored my portion variable.

so something like

```
sum all the sepal lengths of iris flowers which have petal width/length >= critvalue
```

Comment: is that not what you did? Using just the first 5 rows of iris data, can you show what your expected output should be?

Comment: No i counted the number of flowers. The below answers are good solutions. I was close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes quite easy with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
iris<-as.data.table(iris)
iris[,prop_width_length := Petal.Width/Petal.Length]
portion<-as.data.table(seq(from = 0,to = 1,by = 0.001))
cumsum<-vector()
for(i in 1:nrow(portion)){
  cumsum[i]<-iris[prop_width_length >= portion[[1]][i],sum(Sepal.Length)]
}
sigportion<-cbind(portion,cumsum)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `lapply`. There must be a neater way to do it but here goes my version:

```
mySeq<-seq(0,1,0.001)
df<-data.frame(mySeq=mySeq,cumsum=as.numeric(lapply(mySeq,function(X)sum(ifelse(iris$Petal.Width/iris$Petal.Length>=X,1,0)))))
```

In the function I'm checking for the condition and summing up the cases satisfied

The below code should give you the sum of sepal lenths

```
dfSepalLengths<-data.frame(mySeq=mySeq,cumsum=as.numeric(lapply(mySeq,function(X)sum(ifelse(iris$Petal.Width/iris$Petal.Length>=X,iris$Sepal.Length,0)))))
```

You could also modify your code as below to get the same result:

```
library(tidyverse)
data("iris")       
iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(prop_width_length = Petal.Width/Petal.Length)

portion = as.data.frame(seq(0,1,0.001))
cumsum = NULL


for (i in 1:1001) {
  cumsum[i] = sum(ifelse(iris$prop_width_length >= portion[i,1],iris$Sepal.Length,0))
}

sigportion <-  cbind(portion, cumsum)
```